# Vagrant up created VM disappears after completion of vagrant up

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm running the latest versions of Vagrant and VirtualBox.

I'm trying to set up a new VM from a VagrantFile that was provided to me.  When I run:

`vagrant up`

from the directory the VagrantFile lives in, over the course of several hours Vagrant setups the new VM.  I can see the new VM in the VirtualBox GUI while its setting up the new VM.

However, on completion of this process, the VM disappears from within the VirtualBox GUI.

I initially tried this with cygwin, but after that failed and a little bit of research as to where the VM's might get put, I also tried it through windows console hoping to avoid this.  No dice either way.

I've also checked in

`C:/Users/_my_user_/VirtualBox_VMs`

which is empty, and

`C:/cygwin64/home/_my_user_/`

and dont even have a VirtualBox directory.

This whole process takes 6 hours to finish and doesnt even throw an error at the end, which is very frustrating.  Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.  Can happily update question with any requested pertinent information!

Cheers!

Comment: Try `vagrant up --debug`.  Also, even before waiting out an extra 6-hours, visit your home directory.  You'll find a VirtualBox directory there, followed by a directory with your VirtualBox's box name, followed by a "Logs" directory.  You'll see *VERY* detailed log files there.  See if you can figure something out from that!

Comment: @unrivaledcreations oh wow, I didnt even consider it might have a debug mode!  thanks so much!  hopefully at the end of the current debug run I'll at least know what the problem is :)  ++on one of your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant has a debugging mode:

```
vagrant up --debug
```

Because of the variety of hypervisors that Vagrant can utilize, problems that surface on that end can be examined using their logging and debugging mechanisms.  In your case, **VirtualBox** keeps very detailed logs by default.  Those can be found in the `Logs` directory.  Look in your home directory, under `VirtualBox\{virtual_box_name}\Logs`.

In my case, I'm using VMWare's AppCatalyst, so I would find the hypervisor log here:

```
/Users/unrivaled/puphpet/zYQHgJ/.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_appcatalyst/vagrant-{vm_uid}
```

For other hypervisor providers, check their documentation for their logging options and file locations.

Comment: looks like there was some wonky stuff going on in the provision file.

Comment: That can happen.  I've noticed that Vagrant will create a lot of scripts and files and flotsam and jetsam that, if a `vagrant up` fails, gets left behind and makes it choke on itself even after you've applied a fix to something.  So when things get wonky, I just blow it all away and start over at PuPHPet.  That's kind-of the point; keep your files on your "main" computer and build your box as-needed, when-needed, how-needed.  Very flexible once you get it working!